In FME, create new attribute field that shows two values from separate rows

I have an attribute table in FME where the dataset is grouped by the values in Column A (e.g., 257). The rows within each group display the distances between points. I would like to add a new column to each row that calculates the range of Column B values between the current row and the next row (based on the order in Column C).
For example:
For Column A = 257:
Row with Column C = 1 should have a range of 0-9.94.
Row with Column C = 2 should have a range of 9.94-14.01.
Row with Column C = 3 should have a range of 14.01-23.43, and so on.
The challenge is that Column C doesn’t always run from 1 to 6; the count of rows varies dynamically between groups.
What I’ve Tried:
Using the StatisticsCalculator to sum the values in Column B, but that only gives a total, not the range for each row.
Writing logic in a Tester or AttributeManager, but I want the solution to adapt dynamically to varying counts in Column C.

You can do this with adjacent attribute mapping.
In an attributeCreator expand Advanced: Attribute Value Handling and tick Enable Adjacent Feature Attributes and enter 1 into Number of Subsequent Features
Then in the new Attributes section create an attribute called Range, and enter a conditional statement
Test: @Value(colA) = @Value(feature[+1].colA
Value: @value(colB)-@Value(feature[+1].colB
Else: colB
This will create a new value that consists of the value of colB joined with a hyphen to the value of colB of the next value (+1) if the value of colA matches between those two features.
Otherwise it will just set the value to the same as colB (I'm not sure what you want to do for the last feature in a group)
